# how to separate field in oracle contain data varchar and number and date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

how to separate field in oracle contain data var char and number and date 
ex:

```
table1:
column1:MohammadBadarneh_07889855_12021990

create procedure to separate and insert into table2:
table2:
name:Mohammad Badarneh
phone number: 07889855
date: 12-02-1990
```

Answer (score 2):

To just separate string values without validating date format fro example, you can write a similar query.

```
-- sample of data
 with t1(col) as(
   select 'MohammadBadarneh_07889855_12021990'       from dual union all
   select 'SomethingElse_07889855_12021990'          from dual union all
   select 'SomethingDifferentHere_07889855_12021990' from dual union all
   select 'MohammadBadarneh_07869855_11021990'       from dual
  ),
  upos (ps) as(
    select level as ps
      from dual
   connect by level <= 3
  ), 
  PData as(
    select Name
         , Phone
         , to_date(Date1, 'dd-mm-yyyy') date1
      from (select q.*
                 , row_number() over(partition by ps order by ps) rn
              from (select u.ps 
                         , regexp_substr(col, '[^_]+', 1, u.ps) res 
                      from t1
                     cross join upos u
                   ) q
           ) s
     pivot (
       min(res)
       for ps in (1 as Name,2 Phone,3 Date1)
     )
  )

select Name
     , Phone
     , Date1
  from PData
```

Result:

```
Name                    Phone         Date1 
---------------------------------------------
MohammadBadarneh        07889855     12-02-1990 
SomethingElse           07889855     12-02-1990 
MohammadBadarneh        07889855     11-02-1990 
SomethingDifferentHere  07869855     12-02-1990
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5b66/2)

Then you can use `insert` statement to insert output of the above query into your table:

```
   insert into your_table_name
      select Name
           , Phone
           , to_date(Date1, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        from (select q.*
                   , row_number() over(partition by ps order by ps) rn
                from (select u.ps 
                           , regexp_substr(t.your_string_column, '[^_]+', 1, u.ps) res 
                        from Yor_Table_With_String t
                       cross join (select level as ps
                                     from dual
                                  connect by level <= 3
                                  ) u
                     ) q
             ) s
       pivot (
         min(res)
         for ps in (1 as Name,2 Phone,3 Date1)
        )
```

Comment: +1 because I never encountered a column list in WITH before :-) (although apparently, it works only on 11gR2)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Yes, that possibility was introduced in 11gr2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using just regular expressions:

```
with v_data as(
   select 'MohammadBadarneh_07889855_12021990' col1 from dual union all
   select 'JohnDoe_07869856_01011980' col1 from dual
  )
select 
  regexp_replace(col1, '^([[:alpha:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)', '\1') as name,
  regexp_replace(col1, '^([[:alpha:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)', '\2') as phone,
  regexp_replace(col1, '^([[:alpha:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)', '\3') as date1
   from v_data
```

It uses the same regex thrice to cut the string into three parts (separated by _).